# Как отключить редактирование в EditText?

Tags: android

Есть поле ввода EditText, согласно документации `android:inputType="none"` либо `setRawInputType(0x00000000)` должны переводить компонент в нередактируемый режим, но реально это не происходит. То есть и

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editor"
    android:inputType="none" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

и

```
EditText editor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editor);

editor.setRawInputType(0x00000000);
```

ничего не делают.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как оказалось, none (0x00000000) все-таки отключает метод ввода, то есть при клике в поле ввода виртуальная клавиатура не показывается, хотя на физической клавиатуре (например, при работе с эмулятором) можно продолжать редактировать текст.

Возможно, это связано с [дефектом](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2854).